# Milstein scheme for Heston model - rate of convergence

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, simulations, heston

Heston model is described by following SDE
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
dS_t &= \mu S_t dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} S_t dW^S_t \\
d\nu_t &= \kappa(\theta - \nu_t) dt + \xi \sqrt{\nu_t} dW^{\nu}_t \\
\textrm{Corr}[W^S_t, W^{\nu}_t] &= \rho
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If I use Milstein scheme for $\nu _t$ and $S_t$, what will be the rate of convergence of process $S$ (when I compare results with denser mesh)? Is it $1.0$ or no?

Comment: Yes, the Milstein scheme converges in both the mean-square sense and the weak sense with order 1.0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method#Description for example.